# Using linkGrabber to get 'href' from google search in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Ok, so all I want to do is get the very first link inside the first google search. I tried to use beautifoulsoup but it didn't work out at all, I couldn't seem to find a way to get the link. I tried using linkGrabber, so now I get all the urls in the google search (I have limited the results to only 1 per page). My code is:

```
import re
import linkGrabber
import urllib

input = str(input('Give movie name:  '))
input = urllib.parse.quote_plus(input)
imdb_s = '+imdb+review'
n = 1
g_s = 'https://www.google.com/search?q='+ input + imdb_s +'&num=' + str(n)
links = linkGrabber.Links(g_s)
gb = links.find(pretty=True)
print(gb)
```

however when I print, i get like 15 links that are from google and which I do not want to use, I want to focus only on one specific href, and get this. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

you can use the google search library - i think pip install google. This library also relies on beautiful soup, but is fit to return only search results. The problem is that the page that google returns when you search has ads and a bunch of other links that aren't the actual search results.

You can also change your query to "site:imdb.com+" to only search on imbd.

That said, I've stopped using that for my googling needs because it's against googles terms of service. I'm not moralizing anything, but the reality is that I can't seem to get much reliability as google keeps sniffing bots and recaptcha-ing them.

The correct way to do it would be to use google's custom search API - which is also good for only returning the info you need, and it's free for 100 searches per day.

Answer (score 1):

To get the very first link you can use [`select_one()`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) `bs4` method.

It didn't work because you don't specify a `user-agent` (`headers`) which is faking real user visits, so Google won't treat your request as a default request `user-agent` which is: [python-requests](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/589c4547338b592b1fb77c65663d8aa6fbb7e38b/requests/utils.py#L808-L814).

```py
headers = {
  "User-Agent":
  "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}
```

Code and example in the [online IDE](https://replit.com/@DimitryZub1/Google-Scrape-Title-Link-and-append-to-the-dictlist#main.py):

```py
import requests, lxml
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    "User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3538.102 Safari/537.36 Edge/18.19582"
}

html = requests.get(f'https://www.google.com/search?q=minecraft', headers=headers).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

for container in soup.findAll('div', class_='tF2Cxc'):
    title = container.select_one('.DKV0Md').text
    link = container.find('a')['href']
    print(f'{title}\n{link}')

# part of the output:
'''
Minecraft Official Site | Minecraft
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/
Minecraft Classic
https://classic.minecraft.net/
'''
```

---

Alternatively, you can do it as well by using [Google Search Engine Results API](https://serpapi.com/search-api) from SerpApi. It's a paid API with a free trial of 5,000 searches.

The main difference is that you don't have to think about why Google is blocks you, why certain selector is giving wrong output, even though it shouldn't. It's already done for the end-user with a `JSON` output.

Check out the [Playground](https://serpapi.com/playground).

Code to integrate:

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
  "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"), # environment for API_KEY
  "engine": "google",
  "q": "minecraft",
}

search = GoogleSearch(params)
results = search.get_dict()

for result in results['organic_results']:
  title = result['title']
  link = result['link']
  print(f'{title}\n{link}')

# part of the output:
'''
Minecraft Official Site | Minecraft
https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/
Minecraft Classic
https://classic.minecraft.net/
'''
```

> Disclaimer, I work for SerpApi.